# Attach CSV file in mail magento 2.3.2 programmatically?

Tags: magento2.3.2

I am unable to attach CSV file in magento 2.3.2 custom extension controller. 
I am referring below link but its not working.
Link >> https://github.com/extait-com/email-attachment.

Answer (score 0):

I put together an extension which let's you attach files to contact us email.

Works in 2.2 and 2.3

https://github.com/DominicWatts/ContactAttachment

I used extait as basis but found a few other areas needed tweaks

Comment: Hi Dominic Xigen, do you have any idea how I can made the google recaptca to work with your module? I use Magento 2.3.3 version, thank you